# Find the Radius of Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)(2n-1)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Find radius of convergence of series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)(2n-1)!}
$$
I found out a hint to split my series into two:
$$
b_n = \begin{cases} a_{2n-1} & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\ 0 &\text{else}\end{cases}
$$
The radius of even $b_n$ is 0 but there is limit superior in ratio test. And since there is an absolute value when calculating the radius, $(-1)^n$ will be irrelevant.

I can then treat my odd-only series as:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n\cdot n!}
$$
Leaving me with:
$$ \varlimsup_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \left| \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}} \right| = \varlimsup_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \frac{n}{n \cdot (n+1)} = 0
$$
And that means the radius of convergence is $\mathbb{R}$. Is that a correct solution?

Comment: you can also use Hadamard's formula for the radius of convergence and the asymptotic expression of Stirling for the factorial. And yes, the radius of convergence is infinite.

Comment: Use $x^{2n-1}=xt^{n-1}$ where $t:=x^2$.

Comment: The set of convergence is $\mathbb R,$ the radius of convergence is $\infty.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks correct, but, instead of splitting the series, it is much more natural to do\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left\lvert(-1)^{n+2}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(2n+1)!}\right\rvert}{\left\lvert(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)(2n-1)!}\right\rvert}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert x\rvert^2\frac{2n-1}{2n(2n+1)^2}\\&=0.\end{align}So, your series converges for every $x$, which means that the radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Comment: "So, your series converges for every x": Indeed. Refreshing to see something about the radius of convergence that has something to do with what the radius of convergence actually _is_. It's  unfortunate how students often speak as though that $|a_n|^{1/n}$ were the _definition_...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Belive me, I know that…

Answer (score 1):

Use Cauchy-Hadamard directly to obtain the convergence radius $\;R\;$:

$$\frac1R=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{b_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{(2n-1)(2n-1)!}}=0\implies R=\infty$$

Comment: "directly"? Not really. In fact $((2n-1)(2n-1)!)^{1/n}$ has little to do with  it, since that's not the coefficient of $x^n$; what's relevant is $((2n-1)(2n-1)!)^{1/(2n-1)}$.

Comment: For example, the radius of convergence of $\sum x^{2n}/4^n$ is $1/2$, although $(1/4^n)^{1/n}\to 4$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It looks like you're silghtly bored and decided to pick on me lately. Fine.